# Removing rows by index from arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, multidimensional-array, row

I have an array 2500*30 elements (its type is "single") and I need to remove several rows that I know the index. For example:

```
duplicate_ids = [1,4:8,11,859,866,1673,2157,2187,2188,2194,2195];
```

How can I do that? My preference is that to not write a for loop, since I might make mistake (when removing previous row, the index of next rows will change in each rotation).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have a valid license at the moment so I cannot test it to make sure it works, but based on the [documentation on row-removal](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/removing-rows-or-columns-from-a-matrix.html), I believe you could do it that way:

```matlab
mat(duplicate_ids, :) = [];
```